# IOS popviewcontroller removes the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, popviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I'm using storyboard in my app and I'm trying to move bac to a previous view controller using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It works fine but it gives me the right viewcontroller but it removes the navigation bar from it and I cn't figure out why
I used it in other places in my project and it worked with no problems and it's making me go crazy :D

Some body plz help
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show storyBoard screen shot from NavigationController to your ViewController with pop?

Comment: http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/3313/screenshot20130206at104.png

this is the storyboard screen shot

Comment: yes I did
it's working fine with other view controllers

Comment: I found the problem
the problem was that the viewcontroller that i'm popping from had the navigation bar hidden set to yes 
and it passed that property to the other viewcontroller
so all I hadd to do was reset the property to no before popping the view

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem the problem was that the viewcontroller that i'm popping from had the navigation bar hidden set to yes and it passed that property to the other viewcontroller so all I hadd to do was reset the property to no before popping the view

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the navigation bar hidden property to hidden or not in every view controller's viewWillAppear method not from viewDidLoad.